C++ freopen() problem reading from an .txt file
The problem:
For some reason, when I have a .txt file (input.txt) in the same path as my main.cpp the code just wont run, but if I get rid of the .txt file the code runs and prints the matrix (second for loop in main function).
I'm a beginner in C++ so maybe I'm doing something wrong with freopen(), or I'm not doing a proper configuration with my files, idk. Thanks!
The code:
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int const rows = 10;
int const columns = 10;
int matrix[rows][columns]{0};

int minPathWeight = INT_MAX;
int currentWeight = 0;

void dfs(int currentNode, int endNode) {
  if (currentNode == endNode) {
    if (currentWeight < minPathWeight) {
      minPathWeight = currentWeight;
    }
    return;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    if (matrix[currentNode][i] != 0) {
      int weight = matrix[currentNode][i];
      matrix[currentNode][i] = 0;
      currentWeight += weight;
      dfs(i, endNode);
      currentWeight -= weight;
      matrix[currentNode][i] = weight;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
  int nodes, edges;
  cin >> nodes >> edges;

  for (int i = 0; i < edges; ++i) {
    int originNode, endNode, weight = 0;
    cin >> originNode >> endNode >> weight;
    matrix[originNode][endNode] = weight;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
      cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}


I already tried to run it in another machine just to see if there was a problem with mine or VScode but still not working.

freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin); -- Why do this when you could use std::ifstream theFile("input.txt"); and test to see if theFile was opened successfully?  Then the rest of the code (if the file is opened successfully) is simply replacing cin with theFile.

The location of the file depends on what the working directory is set to when the program is run. Also if you are on windows be careful with the file explorer. The default option of "hide extensions for known types' can cause you to create a file named input.txt.txt without you knowing because of the hiding and this would result in c++ not finding the file because input.txt is different from input.txt.txt

@PaulMcKenzie thanks for the suggestion I already implemented it!

Answering my own question...
I tried many things prior to this simple solution...
Apparently I was not considering the spaces in my input file, if you don't have spaces between character or numbers it will read them as one. It makes sense know that I think about it.
incorrect input.txt causing the problem:
9
12
013
022
133
143
154
245
252
362
484
573
682
785

correct format:
9
12
0 1 3
0 2 2
1 3 3
1 4 3
1 5 4
2 4 5
2 5 2
3 6 2
4 8 4
5 7 3
6 8 2
7 8 5

